# How to validate email address with exact gmail or yahoo word by regex?

Tags: regex

What I want to do is to validate an email address with exact gmail or yahoo word and I have tried the following but failed:

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[^gmail$.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/
```

suppose if anyone mistakenly tried to sign up using example@gmal.com or example@mail.com or example@yaho.com or something like that. How can I validate that??

Comment: Why Gmail specifically? What are you trying to achieve?
There are lots of edge-cases such googlemail.com vs gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For regex to validate email you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript).

If you want a simple validator to allow only email addresses that contains @gmail as part of it and allow only letters,numbers,dot and underscores in user name, you can use below regex.

```py
^[a-z0-9._]+@gmail\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RLRUz2/1)